# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':'

Tags: php, ternary-operator

Why am I getting this error the code works on the live demo the developer shows and its the same code? Any help would be most appreciated.

```
$method = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD_OVERRIDE'] ?: $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
```

Comment: I disagree with the closure of this question. Misunderstanding of the tertiary operator is quite common among beginning programmers.

Comment: The problem is probably with the PHP version. ["Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise."](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). If your PHP version is < than 5.3 it'll not work.

Comment: **All of the answers below are wrong.** This is a PHP version mismatch, the above code will work on PHP > 5.3 and fail on lower versions. From [the docs](http://php.net/ternary): Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression `expr1 ?: expr3` returns `expr1` if `expr1` evaluates to `TRUE`, and `expr3` otherwise. So, none of the answers below will properly answer this question. The correct answer is: `$method = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD_OVERRIDE'] ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD_OVERRIDE'] : $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];`

Comment: @HugoDozois - that should be an answer, since the others are incorrect

Comment: @c.cam108 I'll post it ! The question just got reopened few mins ago! Thank you for mentionning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with the fact that the ternary operator is missing an argument as other stated. The problem is probably the PHP version of the server.

Straight from the [PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) :

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.

The way it is written is valid for any server with PHP version equal or above to 5.3.

Else it should be re-written in its equivalent expression :

```
$method = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD_OVERRIDE'] ?  $_SERVER['HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD_OVERRIDE'] : $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
```

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
$method = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD_OVERRIDE'] ?: $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
```

to

```
$method = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD_OVERRIDE'] ? "" : $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
```

OR

```
$method = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD_OVERRIDE'] ? NULL : $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
```

Comment: Ternary operator without the second argument is totally valid. `$a =$x ?: $y` would assign `$x` to `$a`. When the second operator is missing, the first one is took as the second one. [Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). The real problem is about the php version.